# How can I rearrange the order of HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Let's say I have

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

How can I change the order to

```
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

using javascript / jquery or ajax?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In that specific instance, you could use [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
$('#div2').insertBefore('#div1');
```

If you want something more complex, you'll have to explain the logic.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnUXr/)

Comment: @sasdd Does this not solve your question? I notice you've unaccepted my answer...